# pyorient query raises " struct.error: required argument is not an integer"

Tags: python, orientdb, pyorient

I am trying to make a simple SQL query on my OrientDB database using pyorient.
First I encountered a problem where my currently used protocol (38) wasn't supported yet by pyorient. I solved it with [this](https://github.com/orientechnologies/pyorient/issues/27#issuecomment-410819253) solution.
Now when I try to make a simple query like `data = client.query("SELECT FROM cars")` it raises these errors: [screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVw9E.png)
I tried the same query in orientDBstudio successfully.

Any idea what I should try or change? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

may be start by -> data = client.query("SELECT * FROM cars")
The "*" is missing.